# Error replacing period with spaces in list

Tags: r

I have a list of indictors with periods in the name and I want to replace those periods with spaces. I know of the gsub() function that replaces punctuations. But every time I try to replace the dots with spaces the list returns null

```
list_AM = list(list(geo = "EU", sales="West.Europe.Sales",
                     indicator = list("SA","NSA","composites_industry_value","DUCS","WUCS","T30","Rovings",
                                      "Mats","WE.Construction.Gross.output..sales...Real.USD","WE.Construction.Production.index","WE.Glass.Gross.operating.surplus..profits...Nominal.USD",
                                      "WE.Glass.Gross.output..sales...Nominal.USD","WE.Glass.Investment..Nominal.USD","WE.Glass.Production.index","WE.Glass.Value.added.output..As.a.percent.of.GDP",
                                      "WE.Glass.Value.added.output..As.a.percent.of.manufacturing","WE.Glass.Value.added.output..As.a.percent.of.world.total","WE.Industrial.Production.Gross.operating.surplus..profits...Nominal.USD",
                                      "WE.Industrial.Production.Gross.output..sales...Nominal.USD","WE.Glass.Investment..Nominal.USD","WE.Glass.Production.index","WE.Glass.Value.added.output..As.a.percent.of.GDP","WE.Glass.Value.added.output..As.a.percent.of.manufacturing",
                                      "WE.Glass.Value.added.output..As.a.percent.of.world.total","WE.Industrial.Production.Gross.operating.surplus..profits...Nominal.USD","WE.Industrial.Production.Gross.output..sales...Nominal.USD","WE.Industrial.Production.Production.index",
                                      "WE.Industrial.Production.Value.added.output..As.a.percent.of.GDP","WE.Industrial.Production.Value.added.output..As.a.percent.of.world.total","WE.Manufacturing.Gross.operating.surplus..profits...Nominal.USD","WE.Manufacturing.Gross.output..sales...Nominal.USD",
                                      "WE.Manufacturing.Investment..Nominal.USD","WE.Manufacturing.Production.index","WE.Manufacturing.Value.added.output..As.a.percent.of.GDP","WE.Manufacturing.Value.added.output..As.a.percent.of.world.total","WE.Current.account.of.balance.of.payments.in.US...share.of.GDP",
                                      "WE.Employment..total.1","WE.External.debt..total..US.","WE.Foreign.direct.investment..US.","WE.GDP.per.capita..nominal..US.","WE.GDP..nominal..US.","WE.Government.balance..share.of.GDP","WE.Population..total","WE.Reserves..foreign.exchange..US.",
                                      "WE.Reserves..months.of.import.cover","WE.Stockbuilding..real..share.of.GDP","WE.Visible.trade.balance..share.of.GDP","WE.Consumer.price.index","WE.Gross.government.debt..as.a...of.GDP.","WE.Industrial.production.index","WE.Interest.rate..short.term",
                                      "WE.Interest.rate..Yield.on.10.year.Government.Debt.Securities....per.annum.","WE.Services.balance..as...of.GDP","WE.Share.price.index","WE.Unemployment.rate","WE.Capacity.utilisation","WE.Consumption..government..PPP.exchange.rate..nominal..US.","WE.Consumption..government..nominal..US.",
                                      "WE.Consumption..government..nominal..share.of.GDP.1","WE.Consumption..private..PPP.exchange.rate..nominal..US.","WE.Exports..goods...services..constant.prices.and.exchange.rate..US.....of.World","WE.GDP..industry..real","WE.GVA.Agriculture.share.of.GVA","WE.GVA.Industry.share.of.GVA",
                                      "WE.GVA.Manufacturing.of.GVA","WE.GVA.Services..share.of.GVA","WE.Gross.value.added.in.construction..real","WE.Gross.value.added.in.services..real","WE.Imports..goods...services..constant.prices.and.exchange.rate..US.....of.World","WE.Imports..goods..PPP.exchange.rate..nominal..US.",
                                      "WE.Industrial.production.index.1","WE.Investment..government..nominal","WE.Investment..machinery...equipment..nominal","WE.Investment..private..non.residential.structures..nominal","WE.Investment..total.fixed.investment..nominal..US.",
                                      "WE.Investment..total.fixed..nominal..share.of.GDP","WE.Net.investment..nominal..US.","WE.Output.gap","WE.Productivity..trend","WE.Stockbuilding..nominal..US.",
                                      "WE.Stockbuilding..nominal..share.of.GDP","WE.Stockbuilding..real..annual.contribution.to.growth","WE.Trend.productivity.target","WE.World.trade.index","WE.House.price.index","WE.Housing.starts","WE.Interest.rate.on.building.society.mortgages","WE.Market.value.of.housing.stock..LCU",
                                      "WE.Residential.property.transactions","WE.Stock.of.owner.occupied.houses","WE.Consumers..expenditure..durables..nominal","WE.Financial.liabilities..household.sector..as.a...of.disposable.income","WE.Liabilities..debt.other.than.loans..households","WE.Personal.consumer.credit",
                                      "WE.Retail.sales..value.index","WE.Retail.sales..volume.index","WE.Savings..personal.sector.ratio")))
```

For example Instead of "WE.Residential.property.transactions" I want the list to return
"WE Residential property transactions"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the structure, it is a recursive `list`, therefore, functions that loop over the nested list in a recursive way i.e. `rapply` or `rrapply` can be used and apply the `gsub` to match the `.` and replace with space (`' '`).

Note that `.` is a metacharacter that matches any character in regex mode (default case), thus we could match literally by either using `fixed = TRUE` (should be faster) or escape (`\\.`) or place it inside square brackets (`[.]`)

```
library(rrapply)
list_AM2 <- rrapply(list_AM, f = function(x) gsub(".", " ", x, fixed = TRUE))
```

-ouput

```
> list_AM2
[[1]]
[[1]]$geo
[1] "EU"

[[1]]$sales
[1] "West Europe Sales"

[[1]]$indicator
[[1]]$indicator[[1]]
[1] "SA"

[[1]]$indicator[[2]]
[1] "NSA"

[[1]]$indicator[[3]]
[1] "composites_industry_value"

[[1]]$indicator[[4]]
[1] "DUCS"

[[1]]$indicator[[5]]
[1] "WUCS"

[[1]]$indicator[[6]]
[1] "T30"

[[1]]$indicator[[7]]
[1] "Rovings"

[[1]]$indicator[[8]]
[1] "Mats"

[[1]]$indicator[[9]]
[1] "WE Construction Gross output  sales   Real USD"

[[1]]$indicator[[10]]
[1] "WE Construction Production index"

[[1]]$indicator[[11]]
[1] "WE Glass Gross operating surplus  profits   Nominal USD"

[[1]]$indicator[[12]]
[1] "WE Glass Gross output  sales   Nominal USD"

[[1]]$indicator[[13]]
[1] "WE Glass Investment  Nominal USD"

[[1]]$indicator[[14]]
[1] "WE Glass Production index"

[[1]]$indicator[[15]]
[1] "WE Glass Value added output  As a percent of GDP"

[[1]]$indicator[[16]]
[1] "WE Glass Value added output  As a percent of manufacturing"

[[1]]$indicator[[17]]
[1] "WE Glass Value added output  As a percent of world total"

[[1]]$indicator[[18]]
[1] "WE Industrial Production Gross operating surplus  profits   Nominal USD"

[[1]]$indicator[[19]]
[1] "WE Industrial Production Gross output  sales   Nominal USD"

[[1]]$indicator[[20]]
[1] "WE Glass Investment  Nominal USD"

[[1]]$indicator[[21]]
[1] "WE Glass Production index"

[[1]]$indicator[[22]]
[1] "WE Glass Value added output  As a percent of GDP"

[[1]]$indicator[[23]]
[1] "WE Glass Value added output  As a percent of manufacturing"

[[1]]$indicator[[24]]
[1] "WE Glass Value added output  As a percent of world total"

[[1]]$indicator[[25]]
[1] "WE Industrial Production Gross operating surplus  profits   Nominal USD"

[[1]]$indicator[[26]]
[1] "WE Industrial Production Gross output  sales   Nominal USD"

[[1]]$indicator[[27]]
[1] "WE Industrial Production Production index"

[[1]]$indicator[[28]]
[1] "WE Industrial Production Value added output  As a percent of GDP"

[[1]]$indicator[[29]]
[1] "WE Industrial Production Value added output  As a percent of world total"

[[1]]$indicator[[30]]
[1] "WE Manufacturing Gross operating surplus  profits   Nominal USD"

[[1]]$indicator[[31]]
[1] "WE Manufacturing Gross output  sales   Nominal USD"

[[1]]$indicator[[32]]
[1] "WE Manufacturing Investment  Nominal USD"

[[1]]$indicator[[33]]
[1] "WE Manufacturing Production index"

[[1]]$indicator[[34]]
[1] "WE Manufacturing Value added output  As a percent of GDP"

[[1]]$indicator[[35]]
[1] "WE Manufacturing Value added output  As a percent of world total"

[[1]]$indicator[[36]]
[1] "WE Current account of balance of payments in US   share of GDP"

[[1]]$indicator[[37]]
[1] "WE Employment  total 1"

[[1]]$indicator[[38]]
[1] "WE External debt  total  US "

[[1]]$indicator[[39]]
[1] "WE Foreign direct investment  US "

[[1]]$indicator[[40]]
[1] "WE GDP per capita  nominal  US "

[[1]]$indicator[[41]]
[1] "WE GDP  nominal  US "

[[1]]$indicator[[42]]
[1] "WE Government balance  share of GDP"

[[1]]$indicator[[43]]
[1] "WE Population  total"

[[1]]$indicator[[44]]
[1] "WE Reserves  foreign exchange  US "

[[1]]$indicator[[45]]
[1] "WE Reserves  months of import cover"

[[1]]$indicator[[46]]
[1] "WE Stockbuilding  real  share of GDP"

[[1]]$indicator[[47]]
[1] "WE Visible trade balance  share of GDP"

[[1]]$indicator[[48]]
[1] "WE Consumer price index"

[[1]]$indicator[[49]]
[1] "WE Gross government debt  as a   of GDP "

[[1]]$indicator[[50]]
[1] "WE Industrial production index"

[[1]]$indicator[[51]]
[1] "WE Interest rate  short term"

[[1]]$indicator[[52]]
[1] "WE Interest rate  Yield on 10 year Government Debt Securities    per annum "

[[1]]$indicator[[53]]
[1] "WE Services balance  as   of GDP"

[[1]]$indicator[[54]]
[1] "WE Share price index"

[[1]]$indicator[[55]]
[1] "WE Unemployment rate"

[[1]]$indicator[[56]]
[1] "WE Capacity utilisation"

[[1]]$indicator[[57]]
[1] "WE Consumption  government  PPP exchange rate  nominal  US "

[[1]]$indicator[[58]]
[1] "WE Consumption  government  nominal  US "

[[1]]$indicator[[59]]
[1] "WE Consumption  government  nominal  share of GDP 1"

[[1]]$indicator[[60]]
[1] "WE Consumption  private  PPP exchange rate  nominal  US "

[[1]]$indicator[[61]]
[1] "WE Exports  goods   services  constant prices and exchange rate  US     of World"

[[1]]$indicator[[62]]
[1] "WE GDP  industry  real"

[[1]]$indicator[[63]]
[1] "WE GVA Agriculture share of GVA"

[[1]]$indicator[[64]]
[1] "WE GVA Industry share of GVA"

[[1]]$indicator[[65]]
[1] "WE GVA Manufacturing of GVA"

[[1]]$indicator[[66]]
[1] "WE GVA Services  share of GVA"

[[1]]$indicator[[67]]
[1] "WE Gross value added in construction  real"

[[1]]$indicator[[68]]
[1] "WE Gross value added in services  real"

[[1]]$indicator[[69]]
[1] "WE Imports  goods   services  constant prices and exchange rate  US     of World"

[[1]]$indicator[[70]]
[1] "WE Imports  goods  PPP exchange rate  nominal  US "

[[1]]$indicator[[71]]
[1] "WE Industrial production index 1"

[[1]]$indicator[[72]]
[1] "WE Investment  government  nominal"

[[1]]$indicator[[73]]
[1] "WE Investment  machinery   equipment  nominal"

[[1]]$indicator[[74]]
[1] "WE Investment  private  non residential structures  nominal"

[[1]]$indicator[[75]]
[1] "WE Investment  total fixed investment  nominal  US "

[[1]]$indicator[[76]]
[1] "WE Investment  total fixed  nominal  share of GDP"

[[1]]$indicator[[77]]
[1] "WE Net investment  nominal  US "

[[1]]$indicator[[78]]
[1] "WE Output gap"

[[1]]$indicator[[79]]
[1] "WE Productivity  trend"

[[1]]$indicator[[80]]
[1] "WE Stockbuilding  nominal  US "

[[1]]$indicator[[81]]
[1] "WE Stockbuilding  nominal  share of GDP"

[[1]]$indicator[[82]]
[1] "WE Stockbuilding  real  annual contribution to growth"

[[1]]$indicator[[83]]
[1] "WE Trend productivity target"

[[1]]$indicator[[84]]
[1] "WE World trade index"

[[1]]$indicator[[85]]
[1] "WE House price index"

[[1]]$indicator[[86]]
[1] "WE Housing starts"

[[1]]$indicator[[87]]
[1] "WE Interest rate on building society mortgages"

[[1]]$indicator[[88]]
[1] "WE Market value of housing stock  LCU"

[[1]]$indicator[[89]]
[1] "WE Residential property transactions"

[[1]]$indicator[[90]]
[1] "WE Stock of owner occupied houses"

[[1]]$indicator[[91]]
[1] "WE Consumers  expenditure  durables  nominal"

[[1]]$indicator[[92]]
[1] "WE Financial liabilities  household sector  as a   of disposable income"

[[1]]$indicator[[93]]
[1] "WE Liabilities  debt other than loans  households"

[[1]]$indicator[[94]]
[1] "WE Personal consumer credit"

[[1]]$indicator[[95]]
[1] "WE Retail sales  value index"

[[1]]$indicator[[96]]
[1] "WE Retail sales  volume index"

[[1]]$indicator[[97]]
[1] "WE Savings  personal sector ratio"
```

---

If there are multiple `.`s, can use `\\.+` i.e. one or more and replace with `' '`

```
list_AM2 <- rrapply(list_AM, f = function(x) gsub("\\.+", " ", x))
```

Comment: One more question some strings have multiple periods if I replace those with spaces I get 3 spaces is there a way to only make it one space?